# dynamic breadcrumbs using anchor tags and isinViewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Working on creating a small jquery plugin for a client's website that is a simple breadcrumb system using anchor tags, that changes the last element in the breadcrumb list based on which anchor tag is currently visible. Further, I'm using HTML5 data- elements to store each page name, so that I can add that as the second element in the breadcrumb list as well.

For visibility, I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport

This is the fiddle I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/7F59C/4/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="header">head element
    <div id="breadcrumbs" data-page="About">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="currentpage"></li>
            <li class="active"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="gridContainer">
    <div class="space">
        take up some space<br />
        <a class="crumb" id="About" href="#">About Us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
        take up more space<br />
        <a class="crumb" id="Other_heading" href="#">Other heading</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $jbread();
});

$.fn.jbread = function () {

    //set bc as breadcrumbs list
    var bc = $("#breadcrumbs");

    //BUILD CURRENT PAGE BREADCRUMB ITEM
    //set currentpage to current page's data-page value
    var currentpage = bc.data("page");
    //set currentpage_link to current page's url
    var currentpage_link = window.location.pathname;
    //add currentpage as next li in breadcrumbs list
    $(".currentpage").html('<a href="' + currentpage_link + '">' + currentpage + '</a>');

    //UPDATE ACTIVE ITEM IN BREADCRUMB LIST
    $.fn.updateCrumbs = function () {
        var currentactive = $(e.target);
        $(".active").html(currentactive);
    }

    //WORK WITH ISINVIEWPORT PLUGIN
    $('div.gridContainer > a.crumb').updateCrumbs();
    $('div.gridContainer > a.crumb:in-viewport(10)').updateCrumbs();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('div.gridContainer > a.crumb').updateCrumbs();
        $('div.gridContainer > a.crumb:in-viewport(250)').updateCrumbs();
    });

    //STYLE BREADCRUMB LIST

};
```

And, for good measure, CSS:

```
#breadcrumbs ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 2px;
}
#breadcrumbs ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.space {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.spacer {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

INTENDED FUNCTIONALITY:
As the user is scrolling down the page, when one of the anchor tags with the class "crumb" comes intoViewport (which I have set as 250-350 pixels down the page), I would like the list item with the class of "active" to be updated with the anchor tag that just triggered the function. I'm not sure if I'm using $(e.target) correctly, or if it will even reference the correct thing.

I'm hoping to get this function working, and then I need to create an actual demo page to flesh out styling the list after it is populated. That's for another question.

Any thoughts, comments, or criticisms are welcome as I am very new to jQuery and am questioning my logic on this one.

Comment: What do you think the `e` variable does refer to?

Comment: Which event? The scroll event is given as an argument to the `.scroll()` callback, where you need an `e` parameter. And that doesn't even help, because its target is always the `window` on which you registered the event.

Comment: exactly why I'm asking a question on here... I have no idea how to reference the specific anchor tag that triggers the selector.

Comment: Selectors are not triggered, only events are. If you want to reference the elements on which you called the `updateCrumbs()` method on, just use `this`.

Comment: <3 jQuery for having simple fixes.

Thanks

Comment: That's not jQuery, that's just basic javascript.

Comment: oh, sweet! even better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want something like

```
$.fn.updateCrumbs = function () {
    var currentactive = this.text();
    $(".active").text(currentactive);
}
```